# Returning index of vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector that looks like this:

```
c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5..)
```

I want to get the index of when the element changes, i.e. `(1,5,9,...)`
I know how to do it with a for loop, but I am trying a faster way as my vector is very large.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
which(c(TRUE,diff(v1)!=0))
```

Or

```
 match(unique(v1), v1)
```

Or if the vector is sorted

```
 head(c(1, findInterval(unique(v1), v1)+1),-1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, fast and elegant

Comment: @user5726 Do you have elements that repeat after a gap i.e. `c(1,1,1, 2, 2,1,1)`

Comment: `match` version is cute.

Comment: @BrodieG Thanks, but it won't work if there are repeats

Comment: True; still interesting use of `match` only matches first, which usually feels like a limitation.  Also, congrats on 60K.  Feels you blew past 50K.

Answer (score 0):

Another fun approach:

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8)
head(c(1, cumsum(rle(v1)$lengths) + 1), -1)
```

Or if you have `magrittr` then it can become

```
library(magrittr)
v1 %>%
  rle %>%
  .$lengths %>%
  cumsum %>%
  add(1) %>%
  c(1, .) %>%
  head(-1)
```

Result: `1  3  4  5  7  8  9 12`

Might look weird but it's fun to think that through :)

Explanation: `cumsum(rle(v1)$lengths)` gets you almost all the way there, but it'll give you the index of where a sequence ends rather than where the next sequence starts, so that's why we add one to each element, append the index 1, and remove the last element.